# How do I create a UIImageView using only code?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am rather new to Cocoa programming and need some help.

I want to make some image views for units in a game and add them with code, because to put them in the view and make conections in Interface Builder is a lot of work.

I already have found code to create and insert UIImageViews:

```
UIImageView *image0 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRecMake(x,y,w,h)];
image0.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[self.view addSubview:image0];
```

My question is: if I can make an array, then I don't have to write this for every image view, and I put the same image in it?

Comment: This is not an Xcode question. Xcode is the IDE you are using.

Comment: This is still not an Xcode question, no matter how many times you change the tag.

Comment: its an xcode question because i am using xcode for this cause of that its xcode relatet

Comment: Your question does not relate to how to use Xcode itself. If your question were, "How do I set a breakpoint in Xcode?" then it would be an Xcode question. Your question is asking how to program a particular thing using Apple's Cocoa API.

Comment: @killerwakka - No, this is not a question about Xcode the IDE, it's about the Cocoa Touch development frameworks. We reserve the [xcode] tag for questions that only deal with Xcode itself or its build process. Please don't roll back these edits again.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to do it would be something like this. This will create 30 image views with the same image.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfImageViews = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"theImage.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    [arrayOfImageViews addObject:imageView];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    UIImageView *image =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRecMake(x+i*k1,y*i*k2,w,h)];
    image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    image.tag = i+1;
    [self.view addSubview:image0];
}
```